# Facebook news feed from public pages

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a designing problem and I don't fully understand facebook instructions.
I'm implementing an android app and I would like to get news from 2 facebook pages (public news).

I know that there is an access token, but I'm not sure how to get it for these 2 pages. 
I imagined such solution:

1. Create my facebook app (Still my app access token is useless in this situation).
2. Ask clients (these 2 facebook pages) to use my app.
3. Then I could get their news. (?)

Unfortunately creating facebook app and giving necessary permissions is very time-consuming so I want to make sure that this solution is correct.

Or maybe is there a much better/faster solution?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Are you talking about User "profiles", or Pages?

Comment: I edited. Sory I didn't know that there is such difference.